# Modify code to display more than one blurb

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

The code below is for a WordPress bookstore website that outputs a blurb about the author on each book page, pulling the content from the corresponding author page. It works fine in most cases except when there is more than one author, it only shows one author (and sometimes not the primary author).

Is there a way to modify it so that if there is more than one author, it displays blurbs for all of them?

Thanks!

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
<div class="featured-author">
  <div class="widget widget_lpcode">
     <h2 class="widget-title">About the Author</h2>
     <div class="textwidget">
        <?php
           $authors = array();
           $parents = array(
               'Author' => 35
           );
           $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
           foreach( $parents as $parent_name => $parent_id ):
               foreach( $categories as $category ):
                   if( $parent_id == $category->parent ):
                       $authors[] = $category->slug;
                   endif;
               endforeach;
           endforeach;

           $custom_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'authors','post_name__in' => $authors,'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) );  

           if($custom_query->have_posts()) : 
                while($custom_query->have_posts()) : 
                   $custom_query->the_post();
           ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
           <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
           <header class="entry-header">
              <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
           </header>
           <div class="entry-content">
              <p><?php get_the_content_limit(115, ''); ?></p>
              <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>" class="more">More</a></p>
           </div>
        </article>
        <?php
           endwhile;
           else: 
           ?>
        Not Found.
        <?php
           endif;
           ?>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently looping through each category and then assigning the same $author variable to the slug of that category, so if there were multiple categories you're just overriding that $author variable each time, and it will end up equaling the last result.

First, establish a blank authors array:

`$authors = array();`

Then, in your foreach loop, add the result to that array:

`$authors[] = $category->slug;`

Finally, in your $custom_query WP_Query parameters, you'll need to change how you look for the posts, as the 'name' parameter will only accept one slug. In WP 4.4 there is a new `post_name__in` parameter that accepts an array, so you could use

`'post_name__in' => $authors,`

If you can't use WP 4.4, you'll have to get the IDs of each post in the authors array and then use the `post__in` parameter which accepts an array of IDs.

Also, change your 'posts_per_page' parameter from 1 to -1 so it will display all results.

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly. Thanks @johnnyd23! I've updated my question with the correct code (for WP 4.4).